# Validating a form in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to validate a form using JavaScript, but the code doesn't seem to execute. The Form is being processed using php which is working just fine. But, the validation is not working. Can someone please help me with this.

```
<script>
    function validateForm(){
    var x = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var num = document.getElementById('number');
    var size = document.getElementById('size');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var atpos=email.value.indexOf("@"); 
    var dotpos=email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (x.value == null || x.value == "") {
    alert("Please Enter your name");
    x.foucs;
    x.style.background = 'Yellow';
    return false;
    }
    if(!filter.test(email.value){
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    email.value="";
    return false;
    }
    if(num.value == null && num.value == ""){
    alert('Please enter your mobile number');
    num.focus();
    }
    if(!isNan(num.value){
    alert('Please enter a valid number');
    num.focus();
    num.style.background();
    return false;
    }
    return false;


}
</script>
```

And here is my html code.

```
      <form method="post" name="myForm " onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="myprocessingscript.php" >                                         
                                                <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Name" class="text" id="name" />
                                                                                                <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"   class="text" id="email"/>

<input name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" type="text"  class="text"  id="number"/>

<input name="size"  placeholder="Size" type="text" class="text" id="size"  />
                                                                                        <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="button">
```

Comment: Please elaborate _does not work_. Do you get an error, do you get invalid validation?

Comment: What's actually happening? Is it submitting the form to the PHP without executing the Javascript? Are there any script errors?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson Yes! It is submitting the form to the PHP without executing the Javascript code.

Comment: I recommend using a jQuery form validation plugin. It's much more simpler.

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors on the page?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson validateForm not defined

Comment: That would imply that you have asyntax error somewhere and your function isn't being recognised because of it.

Comment: h5validate is a brilliant validation plugin, allows you to use HTML5 built in validation tags and adds HTML5 validation to non-HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4E7D/2/)

Correct the spelling of `foucs` and ensure all references have parenthesis such as:

```
email.focus();
```

Without parenthesis, the function is not called. It's valid Javascript but it won't do anything.

You also missed a closing `)` here:

```
if(!filter.test(email.value){
//                         ^ add another )
```

and here:

```
if(!isNan(num.value){
//                 ^ add another )
```

`!isNan(....)` should be `isNaN(....)`. Javascript is case sensitive and you shouldn't be "notting" it here. `isNaN` is saying "is not a number" so it's already "notted".

On the line below, style has no background function. Looks like you want to assign a value here not call a function:

```
num.style.background(); // change to assign value.
```

On this line, change `&&` to `||`:

```
if(num.value == null && num.value == ""){
//                   ^ should be ||
```

Finally, remove the `return false` at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out with this. The name and email are being validated perfectly. But the number isn't. It is not checking if the user input is number or not. Can you please help me on this. I even replaced isNan with isNan. But still it's not working.

Comment: The condition if(!isNaN(num.value)) is not being checked. It is accepting alphabets also. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you testing the updated fiddle? It works for me in Chrome....... doesn't accept alphabets or blank, only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `x.focus();`

`x.foucs;` is not a valid statement, and neither is `email.focus;`.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't right I don't think:

```
email.focus;
// Try email.focus();
```

and

```
x.foucs;
// Try x.focus();
```

Also looking at your code I don't see a `</form>`

Try this:

```
function validateForm(){
    var x = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var num = document.getElementById('number');
    var size = document.getElementById('size');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var atpos = email.value.indexOf("@"); 
    var dotpos = email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (x.value == null || x.value == "") {
        alert("Please Enter your name");
        x.focus();
        x.style.background = 'Yellow';
        return false;
    }
    if(!filter.test(email.value){
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus();
        email.value="";
        return false;
    }
    if(num.value == null || num.value == ""){
        alert('Please enter your mobile number');
        num.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(!isNaN(num.value)){
        alert('Please enter a valid number');
        num.focus();
        num.style.background = "Yellow";
        return false;
    }

    return true;


}
```